# Blender Freezes my whole system on startup

Tags: windows

Yesterday i installed an Geforce GTX960 into my system, since then When i starup Blender my system freezes i have installed the newest driver and even tried older ones.

The last thing in the startup console says:
updatedeviceparams failed to set 44100, got 48000
alcmmdevplaybackmixerproc wait for single object ex 0*102

Everything else seems to work on my system.

Windows 10
AMD-FX 8320
24gb ram 
GTX 960

Comment: Try updating your OS, If all your drivers are updated, this is probably a bug, report it to Blender Foundation

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Windows is up to date but something changed, now my system don`t freezes anymore now blender just won`t start, i have no clue what has changed but i think its a good sign.

Comment: So this happened after updating Windows?

Comment: No right after installing a new graphics card.

Comment: That's very odd, I think you should report a bug to Blender Foundation